# Insert statement conflict with foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am writing the script for practice and Following is the emp and department table :

```
Create table Employee
(
EmpId       int,
Name        varchar(30),
Designation varchar(50),
DateOfBirth date,
Salary      int,
Department  int,
Gender      char(2),
Primary key(empId),
    foreign key(empId) references Department(DeptId)
)
Create table Department
(
DeptId      int,
Department  varchar(30),
Primary key(DeptId)
)
```

When I am inserting rows into Employee table then I am getting the following error :

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Employee_EmpId". The conflict occurred in database "Ramandeep", table "dbo.Department", column 'DeptId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Below is the row which I am trying to insert :

```
 Insert into Employee(EmpId,Name,Designation,DateOfBirth,Salary,Department,Gender) values (4,'Sam','Accountant','1973-05-13',6500,4,'M')
```

And values are available in Department table

```
Insert into Department(DeptId,Department) values (1,'HR')
Insert into Department(DeptId,Department) values (2,'Operation')
Insert into Department(DeptId,Department) values (3,'IT')
Insert into Department(DeptId,Department) values (4,'Admin')
```

I don't know why I am getting this error. Please help to fix it.

Comment: I think your design is wrong. Why are you setting Employee.EmpId which is the Primary key for that table as a Foreign Key constraint to the Department table? It doesn't make any sense

Comment: The design does look wrong but actually does not throw an error.

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh What I doing wrong here can you please explain?

Comment: Why are you setting the same co.umn as Primary Key as well as Foreign Key? As per the design, it means you can have only 1 employee in each department. So I recommend you should change the design to add a new Column in the Employee table to store Department Id and set it as a foreign key, instead of setting the foreign key in the EmpId column itself

Comment: Now I got your point, I was doing wrong I have to make Department as Foreign key instead of EmpId. Thanks for pointing the Issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design does look wrong but actually does not throw an error. Perhaps you aren't doing things in the right order

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists e;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists d;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> Create table D
    -> (
    -> DeptId      int,
    -> Department  varchar(30),
    -> Primary key(DeptId)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> Create table E
    -> (
    -> EmpId       int,
    -> Name        varchar(30),
    -> Designation varchar(50),
    -> DateOfBirth date,
    -> Salary      int,
    -> Department  int,
    -> Gender      char(2),
    -> Primary key(empId),
    ->     foreign key(empId) references D(DeptId)
    -> )
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> Insert into D(DeptId,Department) values (1,'HR');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> Insert into D(DeptId,Department) values (2,'Operation');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> Insert into D(DeptId,Department) values (3,'IT');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> Insert into D(DeptId,Department) values (4,'Admin');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> Insert into E(EmpId,Name,Designation,DateOfBirth,Salary,Department,Gender)
    -> values
    -> (4,'Sam','Accountant','1973-05-13',6500,4,'M');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from e;
+-------+------+-------------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
| EmpId | Name | Designation | DateOfBirth | Salary | Department | Gender |
+-------+------+-------------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
|     4 | Sam  | Accountant  | 1973-05-13  |   6500 |          4 | M      |
+-------+------+-------------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What I am doing wrong in the code I think it is same which you try

Comment: It's exactly the same (apart from the table names which I changed to protect my db), I posted the answer to prove there was no problem with the code. I can only suggest that the department table did not contain a deptid of 4 at the time of the insert to employee or the error does not arise from the insert to employee that you have shown.

Comment: But I copied your code and paste it into SSMS and execute it but still I am getting the same error. I don't know why

Comment: Works fine for me in sqlserver too.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing wrong, actually I have to make Department as foreign key instead of EmpID. Now I make department as foreign key and execute the script then it works fine. Thanks for the help brother

Answer (score 0):

This error seems as trying to insert a record with a value in the foreign key column that doesn't exist in the foreign table.

if your Department Table has values are available, please check the transaction has been committed in Database.